# Proving Cauchy sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x_n$ be a sequence in the real number set satisfying $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|\le r|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ for all $n\in\Bbb R$, where $0<r<1$.

> Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset\Bbb R$ be a sequence satisfying $$|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|\le r|x_{n+1}-x_n|\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N, |r|<1\;.$$ Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Let $n+2,n+1\ge n_0$. Then $$\begin{align*}|x_{n+2}-x_{n_0}|&=|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}+x_{n+1}-\ldots+x_{n_0+1}-x_{n_0}|\\&\le|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}+|x_{n+1}-x_n|+\ldots+|x_{n_0+1}-x_{n_0}|\\
> &\le r|x_{n+1}-x_n|+r|x_n-x_{n-1})+\ldots+r|x_{n_0}-x_{n_0-1}|\;.\end{align*}$$ Then $$\begin{align*}|x_{n+2}-x_{n_0}|&\le|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|+\ldots+|x_{n_0+1}-x_{n_0}|\\&\le r|x_{n+1}-x_n|+r|x_n-x_{n-1}|+\ldots+r|x_{n_0-1}-x_{n_0}|\;,\end{align*}$$ and $$\begin{align*}|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|&+|x_{n+1}-x_n|+\ldots+|x_{n_0+1}-x_{n_0}|\\&\le r|x_{n+1}-x_n|+r|x_n-x_{n-1}|+\ldots+r|x_{n_0-1}-x_{n_0}|\;,\end{align*}$$ so $$|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|\le(r-1)\left(|x_{n+1}-x_n|+\ldots+|x_{n_0+1}-x_{n_0}|\right)+r|x_{n_0-1}-x_{n_0}|<\epsilon\;.$$ Let $\epsilon=r|x_{n_0-1}-x_{n_0}|$. Since $0<r<1$, $$(r-1)\left(|x_{n+1}-x_n|+\ldots+|x_{n_0+1}-x_{n_0}|\right)<\epsilon\;.$$

I do not know how to continue from there to get epsilon, so if anyone could guide me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to prove it for arbitrary epsilon, not a fixed one.

Comment: $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|\le r|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|\le r^2|x_{n+1}-x_{n-1}|\le \cdots $

Comment: Please check to make sure that I made no errors in transcribing the photograph.

Comment: thank you so much Mr Scott for transcribing it. appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that

$$\begin{align}|x_n-x_{n+p}|&\leq |x_n-x_{n+1}|+|x_{n+1} - x_{n+2}|+\ldots + |x_{n+p-1} - x_{n+p}|\\&\leq r^n|x_0-x_1| + r^{n+1}|x_0-x_1| + \ldots + r^{n+p-1}|x_0-x_1|\\&= |x_0-x_1|\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} r^{n+i}< |x_0-x_1|\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} r^{n+i}\end{align}$$

Use that $0 < r < 1$ and evaluate the geometric sum. Can you take it from here?

Comment: thank you ! but i just dont get why xn and xn+1 is less than r|x_1 - x_0| how did the subscript 1 and 0 come about? :)

Comment: @faith It's not difficult. Notice $|x_n-x_{n+1}| \leq r|x_{n-1}-x_{n}|$ by the definition you gave us. Now again by definition of the sequence we have $|x_{n-1}-x_{n}|\leq r|x_{n-2}-x_{n-1}|$. Putting the last two toghether we have : $|x_{n}-x_{n+1}| \leq r\Big(r|x_{n-2}-x_{n-2}|\Big) = r^2|x_{n-2}-x_{n-1}|\Rightarrow |x_{n}-x_{n+1}|\leq r^2 |x_{n-2}-x_{n-1}|$. If you keep the process, you will get $r^n$ until $|x_{0}-x_{1}|$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Use that, for any $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$$$|x_n - x_m| \leq |x_n - x_{n+1}| + |x_{n+1} - x_{n+2}| + \dots + |x_{m-1} + x_{m}|$$

and

$$|x_n - x_{n+1}| \leq r^n|x_1 - x_0|$$